# How to declare a variable in swift whose datatype is an array of entities without knowing which entity?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I am building an iOS app with Xcode and using CoreData. In the data model there are a few entities, let's say: A, B, C, D, E.

In the homeViewController there are five buttons and each button perform the segue to the detailTableViewController for each entity.

Depending on which button is pressed, you should fetch the information for the corresponding entity. For example, if I press button "B" I should get the Data for the "B" entity in the detailTableViewController.

And here comes the question: how can I declare the variable "entitiesArray" to store the fetch request result if I don't know which entity is going to be pushed until the button is pushed? I have no idea of its data type until the button is pushed.

If there were only one entity "A" I would write:

```
let entitiesArray = [A]()
let request: NSFetchRequest<A> = A.fetchRequest()
entitiesArray = try context.fetch(request)
...
```

However, I don't know the entity that will be pushed.

And using a switch statement in viewDidLoad doesn't solve the problem because I need the entitiesArray to be a global variable to use it inside other functions like numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAt indexPath.

Comment: I’m not exactly providing an answer here, because I don’t truly know the context, nor do know how your objects relate. But you can use POP (protocol oriented programming) concepts with generics. This out on GitHub, it might give you some inspiration https://github.com/antitypical/Result/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Also, you might be able to solve this with a shared parent class using OOP, but I sense here you already are using some form of genetics

Comment: All of your objects will be subclasses of `NSManagedObject` - so you can use that as the type. You still need to work out how to handle the potentially different properties of each different entity; You may be better specialising your view controller through subclassing or protocols

Comment: For conpleteness sake, You can also use `AnyObject` as the type used for your array. More, as usual, in the docs : https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html

Comment: @Losiowaty You wouldn't use `AnyObject` when you can identify a superclass; You *know* you are dealing with `NSManagedObject` subclasses.

Comment: @Paulw11 you are totally right. I just wanted to provide a reference to a generic solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your context via extension:

```
func fetchMOs (_ entityName: String, sortBy: [NSSortDescriptor]? = nil, predicate: NSPredicate? = nil) throws -> [NSManagedObject] {

      let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)

      request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false //as I need to access value
      request.predicate = predicate
      request.sortDescriptors = sortBy
      return try! self.fetch(request) as! [NSManagedObject]
}
```

then you simply call it like this:

```
let mos = context.fetchMOs(String(describing: yourClassofAorBorCorD))
```

The point is using NSFetchRequest's convenience init(:entityName) and struct NSFetchRequestResultType as result type.

Comment: If you do need designated init of NSFetchRequest, using generic helps building similar func.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance. I am a beginner with swift. I have written extensions a few times, but I am not sure where and how I can write this extension.
¿extension NSPersistentContainer { func fetchMOs}? something like this... but where?

Comment: And now I face another problem. If I pushed on the “A” entity I execute the function fetchMOs and get a type [NSManageObject]. However, this data type is useless if I want to access the data inside, for example: [NSManageObject].attribute1ofEntityA <- this is incorrect. It should be A.attribute1ofEntityA. For that I assume I should downcast as! A. But is there a more professional way of doing that?

Comment: Jose, that's when you need generic. It's complex and I can't remember the details but something like <T> where T: NSManagedObject. Maybe someone else can help you with the advance topic.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using the superclass `NSManagedObject` could be to create a protocol and have your array declared to contain objects of that protocol. This could make sense if want to access data the same way for all entities in your UI like getting a name, identifier etc and preferably if it is immutable

Here is a quick example using the built-in protocol `CustomStringConvertible`

```
let entitesArray = [CustomStringConvertible]()
```

implement the protocol in an extension

```
extension A: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "\(someAttribute), \(someOtherAttribute)"
    }
}
```

---

You can have a simple protocol then with title and url and let all entities implement this protocol, you do need to have different names in the protocol do for the attributes so that they do not clash with the atributes in the entities. An example

```
protocol LabelSupport {
    var titleLabel: String { get }
    var urlLabel: String { get }
}
```

And let A implement it

```
extension A: LabelSupport {
    var titleLabel: String {
        return title
    }
    var urlLabel: String {
        return url
        // or perhaps url.path or similar
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to access data the same way for all entities. I just want to use the attribute "title" and add it to a label and the attribute of "url" and add it to a button. The same for all the entities.
The only difference between entities are the NSPredicate, to filter the data obtained. But I am going to do the same with all the data, no matter which entity is called.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I tried to solve the problem using a parent entity for the common attributes and works perfectly. I think this method is a similar way of solving the problem. Again, thank you very much for your help.